# For Azure VM SQL log shipping, What is the reason for requiring storage account to be in the same resource group as SQL VM? Any workaround?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, azure-vm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/log-shipping-configure?view=azuresql

The prerequisite for log shipping in Azure VM based SQL servers is:

> At least two domain-joined Azure virtual machines with SQL Server in
> the same resource group as an Azure storage account for transaction
> log backups.

What is the reason for requiring the storage account to be in the same resource group as SQL vms?

Is there any alternative if one or both VMs are in a different resource group compared to the storage account?

Comment: Guessing here, by putting them in the same resource group, they will fail around inside of the datacenter as a group.  Otherwise, I can't think of a reason since it's using a file share and UNC pathing to get to it, so nothing special going on under the hood there.

Comment: But fail around as a group has no implication to working of log shipping

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool that allows you to do log shipping directly from Azure blob that might be worth a look.

https://github.com/trimble-oss/sql-log-shipping-service

I'm using this to do log shipping between Azure and AWS.  It also supports log shipping from UNC paths and scales to thousands of DBs.

PS

You can use Ola's backups scripts to do BACKUP TO URL. I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/scheffler/7edd40f430235aab651fadcc7d191a89) useful.